# Remove link from product name on WooCommerce my account downloads

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, product

In Woocommerce when we go to My account "Downloads" section, a list of downloads is displayed which contain product name(linked to the product) and link to download the file.

Is there a way to remove the link of product and just display product name?

Comment: Did someone modify the title of this question?

Comment: Hi, you seem to have modified the question and answered your own question. The original question was to remove product link and just place product name and not related to download link.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 3:**

Here is the way to remove the product link from the product name in My account downloads:

```
// Display the product name without the link 
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'custom_account_downloads_product_column' );
function custom_account_downloads_product_column( $download ){
    // Display the product name without the link
    echo esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

[image: enter code here]

Comment: I accidentally approved this answer but it does not answer my question. I am not trying to remove download link, I am trying to remove product link from the product name :)

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for sharing, but I regret to say it did not work. I had to now just copy the Woo template in my theme and edit it.

Comment: @HarishChouhan I have re-updated, tested an it works as I am using dedicated hook for that. tested on WooCommerce 3.2.x et 3.3.x